# Does Tinker Island have an ending?

Tags: tinker-island

I'm just curious if I can "win" or complete the game. If not, does the game at least resolve the plot?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it did -- most people would stop playing if there was a definite ending. I haven't seen it yet either way.

Comment: Are you passed the passage yet? (After the volcano)

Comment: @Isuka you're supposed to comment this on the faulty answer